# Capture Number after a phrase

Tags: python, regex, string

I have strings like:

> 1. Your signing bonus is 123,000
> 2. This year signing bonus is bad. the signing bonus for this year is EUR 123,000
> 3. The bonus is 14,456,  but signing bonus.

I want the output like:

a) If there is any number followed by `signing bonus` keep that part of string and remove everything. **See Expected Output 1 & 2**

b) If no number is followed by `signing bonus` I should get the 1st part of the sting. **See expected output 3**

**Expected Output**

> 1. is 123,000
> 2. for this year is EUR 123,000
> 3. The bonus is 14,456,  but

**My Regex:**

```
match1 = re.findall(r'(?<=\bSigning Bonus\b)\s*(?:\S+\b\s*){0,8}',value, re.I|re.M|re.DOTALL)
```

**It handles Output 1 and Output 2 but can't handle Output 3.**

I am also open to solution which can be done without regex also!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are okay using `re.sub` then you can use this regex to replace matched text with empty string,

```
^[^\d\n]*signing bonus\s*|\s*signing bonus[^\d\n]*$
```

In first two cases, you are intending to capture the string after `signing bonus` but in third case, your intended string is before `signing bonus`, hence for that you need another regex using alternation.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0UDX9d/1)**

Python code,

```
import re

arr = ['Your signing bonus is 123,000','This year signing bonus is bad. the signing bonus for this year is EUR 123,000','The bonus is 14,456, but signing bonus.']

for s in arr:
 print(s, '-->', re.sub(r'^[^\d\n]*signing bonus\s*|\s*signing bonus[^\d\n]*$', '', s))
```

Prints,

```
our signing bonus is 123,000 --> is 123,000
This year signing bonus is bad. the signing bonus for this year is EUR 123,000 --> for this year is EUR 123,000
The bonus is 14,456, but signing bonus. --> The bonus is 14,456, but
```

Answer (score 4):

try below code.

```
s1 = "Your signing bonus is 123,000"
s2 = "This year signing bonus is bad. the signing bonus for this year is EUR 123,000"
s3 = "The bonus is 14,456, but signing bonus."
regex = '[0-9]'
import re
def format_string(s):
    for subs in s.split('signing bonus'):
        if re.findall(regex, subs):
            print subs.strip()

format_string(s1)
format_string(s2)
format_string(s3)
```

output is :

```
is 123,000
for this year is EUR 123,000
The bonus is 14,456, but
```

Comment: I can't accept both and hence I accepted above answer as one line answer works for me better to stuff in the bigger code!! Having said that, I have upvoted your answer and thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This will print your answer:

```py
statements = [
    'Your signing bonus is 123,000',
    'This year signing bonus is bad. the signing bonus for this year is EUR 123,000',
    'The bonus is 14,456, but signing bonus.',
]
for statement in statements:
    ans = statement.split('signing bonus')
    if not ans:
        print('')
        continue
    for i in range(len(ans) - 1, -1, -1):
        for word in ans[i].split(' '):
            try:
                number = int(word.replace(',', ''))
                print(ans[i].strip())
                break
            except:
                pass
```

Output:

```
is 123,000
for this year is EUR 123,000
The bonus is 14,456, but
```